# How to get CaffeineCacheManager from application context in SpringBoot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, applicationcontext, caffeine

I want to use custom `WrappingCacheManager` as a decorator for `CaffeineCacheManager`.

Currently configuration is created imperatively with `Caffeine.newBuilder()...`, and I want to replace it with a declarative version using a property:

```
spring.cache.caffeine.spec=maximumSize=500, expireAfterWrite=60s
```

Unfortunately, there are no beans of type `CaffeineCacheManager` in app context, so it is impossible to inject it and wrap in a natural way.

**Intention:**

```
// now it fails with NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

@Configuration
class CacheConfig1 {

  @Bean
  CacheManager cacheManager(CaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager) {
    return new WrappingCacheManager(caffeineCacheManager);
  }
}
```

**Currently used variant:**

```
@Configuration
class CacheConfig2 {

  @Bean
  CacheManager cacheManager() {

    var cfg = Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).maximumSize(500);

    CaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
    caffeineCacheManager.setCaffeine(cfg);

    return new WrappingCacheManager(caffeineCacheManager);
  }
}
```

Fragment of dependencies in **pom.xml**

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

...

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
  <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**How to inject `CaffeineCacheManager` into a bean creation method and be able to create a wrapper `CacheManager` around it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to inject `CaffeineCacheManager`, but at least it is possible to create Caffeine config from a string with `Caffeine.from` function. So injection of the property via `@Value` is a satisfactory solution.

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(
  @Value("${spring.cache.caffeine.spec}") String caffeineSpec
) {

  var cfg = Caffeine.from(caffeineSpec);

  CaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
  caffeineCacheManager.setCaffeine(cfg);

  return new WrappingCacheManager(caffeineCacheManager);
}
```